# How do I solve for this system of equations that has 4 variables?

Tags: systems-of-equations, factoring

So, I have a question in a textbook that asks the following:
$$3x^3 + 4x^2 - x + m$$
It says this equation has two identical linear factors. It asks for the possible real values of m, and the zeroes for each case.

So what I figured out is that two identical linear factors would be
$$(ax+b)^2$$
and FOILing that gets
$$a^2x^2 + 2abx + b^2$$
From there I would have to figure out a binomial that when multiplied by the above gets the original equation. So I wrote it out like this:
$$(a^2x^2 + 2abx + b^2)(cx+d) = 3x^3 + 4x^2 - x + m$$
After that, I mutliplied the two equations to get this massive, confusing thing:
$$ca^2x^3 + da^2x^2 + 2a2bcx^2 + 2a2bdx + b^2cx + db^2 = 3x^3 + 4x^2 - x + m$$

So finally, I made a system of equations for this which turned out to be:
$$2a2bd + b^2c = -1$$
$$ca^2 = 3$$
$$da^2 + 2a2bc = 4$$
$$db^2 = m$$

And this is where I'm stuck. I can't find a single variable, let alone m. Did I do something wrong? Is the system of equations even possible? I can elaborate on my process getting the equations if that helps.

Comment: I think each occurrence of $2a2b$ above should read $2ab$, but that doesn't make things much better. Are you looking for arbitrary real solutions or integer solutions?

Comment: You're definitely right on the first part, it should be 2ab. I'm looking for any real solution, not just integers.

Comment: I see. If you are working over the reals, you can at least assume $a=1$ and $c = 3$, which make things a bit simpler.

Comment: Hint: two identical linear factors means a double root, which must also be a root of the derivative.

Comment: Wait, why does a = 1? Couldn't it be something like root 3 if c = 1?

Answer (score 1):

$3x^3+4x^2−x+m$ is a polynomial of degree $3$, and thus should have three roots, counting duplicates. Since it has two identical linear factors,
$$3x^3+4x^2−x+m=3(x-a)^2(x-b)$$
From then, expand and simplify to get
$$x^3+\frac{4x^2}{3}−\frac{x}{3}+\frac{m}{3}=(x^3+(-2a-b)x^2+(a^2-2ab)x+a^2b)$$
Thus by comparing coefficients of $x$ and $x^2$, $(a,b)=(-1/3,-2/3),(-1/5,-14/15)$. These are the zeroes of the equation for $m=-2/9$ and $-14/125$ respectively.